# Event notifications between iframe and parent

Tags: javascript, events, listener, dom-events, event-listener

I am trying to send an event to iframes which have been opened by the application based on few events which should be prior registered by iframes.

I cannot figure out how. I use jQuery but I don't expect the iframes to be nice citizens to implement listeners in jQuery. Though I can mandate it - I am still looking for normal Javascript notifications.

Scenario

- iframe A registers for entry event
- iframe B registers for entry event

The parent gets notified by server and it sends events to both these iframes.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method on the parent that lets child pages register a listener.

something like

```
window.registerListener(callback)
```

that way it's up to the iframes to tell the parent window that it's listening.

then use

```
window.parent.registerListener(function() {   
 // do stuff 
});
```

It'll only work if the iframes are on the same domain obviously.

Comment: I don't understand why it would work only for iframes in same domain. It has no same domain policy.